# Does Service Fabric provide a mechanism for distributed transactions?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have a set of micro services that all communicate via REST API.  Each service will be implemented as a stateful actor in Service Fabric and each will have access to the reliable collections we have in service fabric.  It is imperative that these services act in a transactional manner.  We are architecting this solution right now, and there is a debate on the ability for Service Fabric's ability to do distributed transaction coordination.  If distributed transactions are not supported (as some are claiming) then the solution will be architected using Nuget packages to update functionality.  I think this comes with its own set of problems almost like the old COM components.

Does Service Fabric have a distributed transaction coordinator for Stateful Serivces using Web API communications?

Comment: Could you explain what your approach to package updates has to do with distributed transactions?

Comment: Mutually exclusive.  The problem is this.  When an operation is done, it will route through multiple microservices that will do one or more operations on a database.  Once all the microservices are done, we need a final commit on the transaction to ensure everything was saved.  The problem with the package updates, is unless the developers are disciplined enough to version their NUGET packages (and they aren't) it will be possible to release a NUGET into prod that will affect all packages causing problem, where as with REST API it is less likely to be catastrophic.

Comment: Just need to know if Service Fabric supports Distributed Transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, SF transactions work on the level of a service replica. Maybe the quorum got people confused, even though this feels like a distributed transaction, it's not something you as a developer can use.

> Strong consistency is achieved by ensuring transaction commits finish
>   only after the entire transaction has been logged on a majority quorum
>   of replicas, including the primary.

### Note:

Distributed transactions cause more [issues](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/01/patterns-for-distributed-transactions-within-a-microservices-architecture/) than they solve, I'd recommend you read about [Event Driven Architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/event-driven) instead.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I'll look at the event driven architecture as a possible solution instead of a monolithic mass of code they want to put into place.